# msp430 flasher in Contiki (exp5438 uploading)

Tags: upload, msp430, contiki

I'm trying to upload the blink.c file in Contiki on a exp5438 board. I'm running Instant Contiki 2.6 on my MacBook inside VirtualBox.

When I try to do the upload to the board, it gives me this error for the msp430 flasher! Is there a work around which can help me run the blink program on the board? I'm really pulling my hair out on this. :D

```
msp430flasher -n msp430x5438a -e ERASE_MAIN -w blink.hex -v -z [VCC]  
/bin/sh: 1: msp430flasher: not found  
make: *** [test-blink.upload] Error 127
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the MSP430Flasher tool from TI (available for win32 and linux), and also of course a MSP430 FET progammer: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_Flasher_-_Command_Line_Programmer

You might need to edit also the platform/exp5438/Makefile.exp5438 file and change the msp430flasher commands at the bottom for MSP430Flasher (mind the case-sensitiveness!).